# Find the method of Schulz to find the inverse of a matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

I need to find the well-know method of Schulz : $$X_{n+1} = X_{n}(2I - AX_{n})$$

The initial problem is to find the *root* of the function $f(X) = X^{-1} - A =0$ which is the inverse of A.
The Newton iteration is given by : $$X_{k+1} = X_{k} - [f'(X_{k})]^{-1}f(X_{k})$$

They tell me that the derivative *f'(X)* is equivalent to $g(X) = X^{-1}$ with **g** a *linear operator* defined as $$E \mapsto -X^{-1}EX^{-1}$$
In other words, the application of $g'(X)$ to a matrix E gives us the matrix $-X^{-1}EX^{-1}$.

So, from $X_{k+1} = X_{k} - [f'(X_{k})]^{-1}f(X_{k})$ we can rewrite it as $$X_{k} - [f'(X_{k})]^{-1}(X_{k}^{-1} -A)$$

but here is $f'(X_{k})$ applied to the matrix $(X_{k}^{-1} -A)$ ? What to do with the $f^{-1}$ ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've correctly noted, for each $X$, $f'_X$ is a linear operator on matrices such that for all $Y$
$$f'_X[Y]=-X^{-1}YX^{-1}\text{.}$$
Therefore ${f'_X}^{-1}$ is also such a linear operator. It must satisfy
$${f'_X}^{-1}[-X^{-1}YX^{-1}]=Y\text{.}$$
Therefore
$${f'_X}^{-1}[Y]=-XYX\text{.}$$

Comment: But here is it applied to $(X_{k}^{-1} -A)$ or $(X_{k})$ ?

Comment: to $X_k^{-1}-A$,

Comment: So I need to replace E by $X_k^{-1}-A$ ?

Comment: That's what you have to do, yes.